# list comprehension working like tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, tuples, list-comprehension

I was creating a simple program for a calculation
but I can not do the array calculation, is there any silly error in my syntax?

Error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

on line:

```
A[j][k]-=(A[i][k]*A[j][k])/A[i][i]
```

Of this code:

```
A = [[0 for x in range(i)] for y in range(j)]

def GaussJordan(A,B,X):
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    for j in range(0,len(A)):
        if(i!=j):
            for k in range(i,len(A)):
                A[j][k]-=(A[i][k]*A[j][k])/A[i][i]
```

I'm using python 3.6.1, on spyder 3.1.4

Comment: Are you sure you're passing the same A that you created in the assignment above?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation, the code you posted won't even run as is.

Comment: there is some disconnect here ... I would assume you would get a divide by zero error ... you left out some parts of your sample code i think

Comment: Yes, only this A exists in the code

Comment: Data structures work fine for me. I get `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`, as expected.

Comment: the program run, but i don't get the zero division error, only the tuple
https://repl.it/Ly3Q/0

Answer (score 0):

These lines in your program:

```
A[0] = 3, 0.1, -0.2
A[1] = 0.1, 7, -0.3
A[2] = 0.3, -0.2, 10
```

are creating tuples.  You cannot reassign elements within a tuple, which is what `A[j][k]-=(...)` tries to do.

Also, this is a perfect example of why you should post code *directly in your question*, not in images or on a third party website.

If the code had been easily viewable in your question, it would have been much easier to answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it was simple.
and sorry for not posting the code direct in the post, I thought that posting it whole would pollute the post